# Android: Communicate with worker thread to send messages

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send messages from one android device to another via tcp. The sending device sends to a PC used as server which then sends the message to the other device.
In order to receive messages I run a thread parallel to the UI-thread which updates the user interface using a handler to show the message. This works fine.

Right now I am using an AsyncTask to send messages, which creates a socket, then sends the message an then closes the socket again. So every time I want to send a message I have to connect and disconnect.

```
public class SendTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

static final String TAG = "SendTask";

private Socket soc;
private String theIp;
private int thePort;

public SendTask(String pIp, int pPort){
    theIp = pIp;
    thePort = pPort;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    try {
        soc = new Socket(theIp, thePort);
        soc.getOutputStream().write(arg0[0].getBytes());
        soc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "failed to create socket");      
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

I would rather have a solution where I create a thread which opens the socket and then every time a button is clicked sends a text recevied from an EditText. Is there a solution for this that is similar to the receiving thread? I am struggling with how to tell the created thread when to send a message without accessing the UI from that Thread.

The sending Thread looks as follows:

```
public class ReceiveClient implements Runnable {

static final String TAG = "ReceiveClient";

public static final int NEW_INPUT = 101;

private Socket soc;
private String theIp;
private int thePort;
Handler handler;

public ReceiveClient(String pIp, int pPort, Handler pHandler){
    this.theIp = pIp;
    this.thePort = pPort;
    handler = pHandler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d(TAG, "try to create socket");
    try {
        soc = new Socket(theIp, thePort);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "failed to create socket");      
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "running");
    try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            byte b[] = new byte[16];
            int count = soc.getInputStream().read(b, 0, 16);
            if(count > 0){
                String s = new String(b);
                Log.d(TAG, "received: " + s);
                displayMessage(s);
                }
            }
        Log.d(TAG, "done");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
    }
}

private void displayMessage(String text){
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = NEW_INPUT;
    msg.obj = text;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}
}
```

Comment: you need to use Handler but in opposite way ... try HandlerThread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use some kind of blocking queue. Handle reading and writing in separate threads - this is thread safe ie there wont be any conflicts if one thread reads from socket and another writes to it.

Your reader thread needs improvement - InputStream.read will block when there is no input available, so you Thread.isInterrupted check is useless. Instead I suggest you skip isInterrupted check and just close socket when you want stop reading, this will cause your read() to unblock.

In your writer thread do something like this

```
 private ArrayBlockingQueue<String> writerQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>( 10 );
 private String stopSignal = "whatever";       

 public void stopWriter() { // this can safely called from other threads and will cause writer thread to stop
     writerQueue.put( stopSignal );     
 } 

 // this can also safely called from other threads
 public void sendMessage( String newMessage ) {
     writerQueue.put( newMessage );
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
     String currentMessage = writerQueue.take(); // if there are no messages in queue this will block
     if( currentMessage == stopSignal ) // == comparison here is correct! we want to check for object equality 
         return; // stop signal received
     // write your string here
 }
```

In your UI send messages using

```
writerThread.sendMessage( "Whatever you want to send );
```

and when done finish thread with

```
writerThread.stopWriter();
```